# Prevent default js for a basic form

Tags: javascript

I have a basic html form and when the user is successfully submitting the form I am displaying a pop-up. However, during that time two things occurs:

1. The popup is only displayed for 1-2 seconds
2. The page is reloaded and therefore going back to the top of the page

I would like to avoid those 2 events and apparently I have to use `event.preventDefault()` but I don't know where to use it

```
const messageSubmitContactForm = () => {
    const form = document.getElementById("contact-form");
    form.onsubmit = function(){
        displayPopUpSent()
    };
}

const displayPopUpSent = () => {
    const popup = document.getElementById("popup-sent");
    popup.style.display="block";

}

const app = () => {
    messageSubmitContactForm();
}


app();
```

**form**

```
 <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> content </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it here

```
form.onsubmit = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    displayPopUpSent()
};
```

#### Update:

You need to add the `action` url too in your `<form>` element (currently it is an empty string)

I have created a simple snippet to illustrate a little bit, maybe this will clear it up for you.

```js
const messageSubmitContactForm = () => {
  const form = document.getElementById("contact-form");
  form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    displayPopUpSent()
  };
}

const displayPopUpSent = () => {
  const popup = document.getElementById("popup-sent");
  popup.style.display = "block";

}

const app = () => {
  messageSubmitContactForm();
}


app();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="message" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <div id="popup-sent" style="display: none">Data is sent</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, it is working. But actually it seems the form is actually not send and the data on the form in not refreshed. What can I do for that?

Comment: @Sophia2000 I have added a simple snippet to explain a bit, check my updated answer.